# Design simple code first movies database (many to many) EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm doing some tutorial on ASP MVC and the guy in the video only uses 1 genre per movie, but I'm interested in knowing on how to make a movie have multiple genres. Example, how do I make this code:

```cs
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Genre> Genre { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

generate some tables like this:

**Movie**

- Id (Primary Key)
- Name

**Genre**

- Id (Primary Key)
- Name

**MovieGenresRelation**

- Id (Primary Key)
- MovieId (References Movie.Id)
- GenreId (References Genre.Id)

I tried adding the MovieGenresRelation class but then how do add reference properties to the Movie class?
Anyway I think that's not how I should go about to do this so please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Pretty sure Genre just needs a new property: `public ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }`. You can check out [this example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) to which you can use as an example.

Comment: Entityframework creates all you need. If you want to add a new genre to a movie, you simply extract the movie and add whatever genre you want to the list of Genres and then saves it again.

Comment: You might consider updating the post title because what are you describing is `many-to-many` relationship.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Seems I was wrong and that's exactly what was needed.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes just did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track (you describe a many-to-many relationship).

You can actually do it with an `ICollection` on both sides of the relationship in EF6, but in EFCore you have to make the intermediate table yourself. In EF6, you could add this to `Genre`:

```
public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies {get; set;}
```

As far as reference properties in the intermediate go, just add them the way you would expect:

```
public virtual Movie Movie {get; set;}
public virtual Genre Genre {get; set;}
```

The primary difference is that the properties in `Movie` and `Genre` would point to `MovieGenreRelation` instead of each other.